# in spl_autoload_register function i need only class name as parameter

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

PHP :

```
    <?php
define("APP_PATH",dirname(__FILE__));
function autoload($className){
    require_once APP_PATH."classes/".$className.".php";
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
?>
```

i wanna autoload function parameter only send class name, but it add folder path to it....
for example if i write :

```
$c = new MyClassName();
```

autoload's parameter be "MyClassName" but it send "FolderName/MyClassName"...??

autoload function is in this folder "xampp/htdocs/game/app/myApp/" 
and classes folder is in this folder "xampp/htdocs/game/app/myApp/classes/" 
i wanna load "xampp/htdocs/game/app/myApp/classes/MyClassName.php" but 
it laod "xampp/htdocs/game/app/myApp/classes/myApp/MyClassName.php"

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function( $className ) {
    require_once APP_PATH."classes/".APP_PATH."/".$className.".php";
});

$c = new Class(); // Should now load automatic
```

Comment: no it doesn't work.... it require this path :  MyApp/classes/MyApp/ClassName.php not this path : MyApp/classes/ClassName.php